Error: Can't find end of central directory : is this a zip file ? when parsing a shp file
I am working with vue3 to load a shp file.
the shp library used is https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/shapefile-js. shpjs 's version is "^5.0.1".
here is the code
   <el-upload
            ref="uploadRef"
            action="/"
            v-model:file-list="state.uploadList" 
            :on-change="uploadFile"
            >
                <template #trigger>
                    <el-button type="primary">select file</el-button>
                </template>
    
    </el-upload>



import shp from 'shpjs';
import { Feature, GeoJSON } from 'geojson';
const uploadFile = async (file) => {
    const format = file.name.split('.').at(-1).toLowerCase();
    let geojson: FeatureCollection<any>;
    switch (format) {
      case 'shp': {
        console.log( await file.raw.arrayBuffer()  );
        const parsed = await shp(await file.raw.arrayBuffer());
        geojson = parsed;
        break;
      }
  }
}

await file.raw.arrayBuffer() outputs

ArrayBuffer(59664156) byteLength: 59664156

but parsing shp from buffer - shp(await file.raw.arrayBuffer()) throws an error
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Can't find end of central directory : is this a zip file ? If it is, see https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html
    at h.readEndOfCentral (shpjs.js?v=9c11b5bb:1045:63)
    at h.load (shpjs.js?v=9c11b5bb:1065:40)
    at shpjs.js?v=9c11b5bb:290:23
    at async unzip_default (shpjs.js?v=9c11b5bb:6488:3)
    at async parseZip (shpjs.js?v=9c11b5bb:6970:15)
    at async Module.loadGeojson (shp.ts:61:24)


if you're file that was uploaded end in .shp it's not a zip file it's a shape so you want to use the parseShp method import {parseShp} from 'shpjs' or it may be available as shp.parseShp and pass the array buffer to that i.e. await parseShp(await file.raw.arrayBuffer());
